# Apple Push Notification: Sending high volumes of messages

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using PHP to connect to apns to send some notifications to multiple devices, although the question is more conceptual so it doesn't have to be specific to PHP. I will be sending to about 7000 devices (and growing) all at the same time. My process runs ONCE per day and broadcasts to all devices, so I am not constantly re-opening a connection.

```
open connection to apple  
loop over device tokens  
    create payload aggregating all devices  
end loop  
write to socket ONCE with whole payload for 7000 devices  
close connection
```

Can I do like above pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Approach here is,

```
you can open the connection.
perform as many writes as you like.
just make sure you check the connection status after each write
close the connection.
```

As each write is considered as a message specific to device, you can write one message at a time. But you can open a connection once and write as many you can.

Answer (score 0):

That is a correct approach but you need to check for APN Feedback and remove the "stale" devices. Apple will give you a list of tokens that they think are no longer valid. You should prune your database and never send to those tokens again.

Comment: How to aggregate all device tokens in php?